# madvise system call with MADV_SEQUENTIAL call takes too long to finish

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, mmap

In my code I am using an external C library and the library calls madvise with MADV_SEQUENTIAL option which takes too long to finish. In my opinion only calling madvise with MADV_SEQUENTIAL is enough for our job. My first question is, why multiple madvise system calls are made, is there a logic in calling madvise with different options sequentially? My second question is, do you have any idea why madvise with MADV_SEQUENTIAL takes too long, sometimes about 1-2 minutes?

```
[root@mymachine ~]# strace -ttT my_compiled_code
...
13:11:35.358982 open("/some/big/file", O_RDONLY) = 8 <0.000010>
13:11:35.359060 fstat64(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=953360384, ...}) = 0 <0.000006>
13:11:35.359155 mmap2(NULL, 1073741824, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 8, 0) = 0x7755e000 <0.000007>
13:11:35.359223 madvise(0x7755e000, 1073741824, MADV_NORMAL) = 0 <0.000006>
13:11:35.359266 madvise(0x7755e000, 1073741824, MADV_RANDOM) = 0 <0.000006>
13:11:35.359886 madvise(0x7755e000, 1073741824, MADV_SEQUENTIAL) = 0 <0.000006>
13:11:53.730549 madvise(0x7755e000, 1073741824, MADV_RANDOM) = 0 <0.000013>
...
```

I am using 32-bit linux kernel: 3.4.52-9

```
[root@mymachine ~]# free -lk
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4034412    3419344     615068          0      55712     767824
Low:        853572     495436     358136
High:      3180840    2923908     256932
-/+ buffers/cache:    2595808    1438604
Swap:      4192960     218624    3974336


[root@mymachine ~]# cat /proc/buddyinfo 
Node 0, zone      DMA     89     23      9      4      5      4      4      1      0      2      0 
Node 0, zone   Normal   9615   7099   3997   1723    931    397     78      0      0      1      1 
Node 0, zone  HighMem   7313   8089   2187    420    206     92     41     15      8      3      6
```

Comment: The question as it stands is too broad - please post some relevant code. A minimal example would be nice.

Comment: library is close-source so I can't see what is inside the library and this call done in the library blocks my code.

Comment: Can you at least show the output of `strace -ttT`?

Comment: I have edited the question and added strace -ttT output

Comment: Are you sure it's the `madvise` call that takes 1-2 minutes? It's just a hint to the kernel on how to handle the memory range. Furthermore, you are allocating 1gb of memory, so maybe some pages are swapped out and that's causing the slowdown?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, but since I don't have the source code of the library I cannot be 100% sure. What you say makes sense, but the test environment was not using swap area. My test environment is not available right now, but when I could test it again I will test it again with swap in my mind.